# vSphere vApp IP address configuration. How does vApp really work?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, virtual-network

I have a pool of ESXi-5.5.0 servers that I have configured a single vApp on. This vApp is configured in transient mode to configure IP addresses from an IP pool I specified. I assigned a single virtual machine to this vApp and am trying to get IP addresses, to no avail. I don't really understand how vApp works, the hosts are configured to use DHCP but always get apipa (169.254.0.0/16) addresses in the case of windows hosts, when then dhcp client times out. The same happens on linux guests. I confirmed that the pool is on the correct virtual switch, and the hosts are on the same network. When I manually assign addresses, I can ping the gateway and access network resources.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this VMWare KB [Post](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1031476) can resolve your issue. Try and let me know the result.